# Scheduled Report(task) Monitor

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, database-design, scheduling, task

I have to develop a system to **monitor** the **generation/transmission** of reports.

- System data will be stored in database tables (Sybase)
- Reports will be generated with different schedules ("mon-fri 10pm", "sat 5am", "1st day of the month", etc.)
- System will just monitor that the reports were created.  It will not create the reports itself.
- System will notify appropriate personnel when a report did not finish.
- System will maintain a log of all generated reports

Anyone know of a good(tried and proven) table(s) design for storing the task shedules?.  I already have an idea, but I don't want reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'm searching for information on how the cron logic works.

Answer (score 1):

If you really are going to support complex schedules of all those types, I am not sure it is a good idea to try to invent an equally complex relational DB schema for all the **details** of those schedules.

I would consider designing an XML schema for schedules' details and, if you really need to store schedules in a relational database, storing the XML data in a column. You could use columns for those attributes of schedules that are applicable to a schedule of any type (like schedule name or who modified it last time and when).

For example, assuming that a schedule can be used for more than one report, you could do something like this:

```
Table: Schedule
---------------
Columns:
    ID                  - Surrogate key to refer to schedules
                          from other tables.

    Name                - Short textual description of the schedule
                          (to be shown in GUI).

    ...

    Details             - XML containing all the details of
                          the schedule (frequency, exceptions,
                          complex combinations of simple schedules, 
                          whatsoever).
```

Even if your application has to answer questions like "what reports are supposed to be due by a given date/time", I think you must have really, really large number of schedules to justify the overhead of using relational schema to store nitty-gritty schedule details in separate columns (and, perhaps, in multiple tables).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table **schedule** with the columns

- id
- name
- mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun
- day
- month
- year
- time (h*60+m)

your examples would be:

**mon-fri 10pm**

```
mon, tue, wed, thu, fri = true, time=22*60, the rest are NULL
```

**sat 5am**

```
sat=true, time=5*60, the rest are NULL
```

**1st day of the month**

```
day=1, the rest are NULL
```

You could also have a table **reports** with the columns

- id
- name
- schedule_id

and a table **report__schedule___late** with the columns:

- id
- date_time
- report_id